# AWS moving large amount of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am moving a large amount of objects in `AWS` `S3` via the `AWS management console`.

My question is, if I shutdown my computer/log-out of amazon, will it kill my transfer?
If yes what can I do about it? I'm not copying, I'm moving(Cut,Past). what will happen? Is there a way to pause it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted the question I had just started moving a folder in S3 and realized that it will take days. When I left work I forgot about the transfer and just shutdown my computer. Fortunately when I arrived this morning and logged into AWS the transfer continued fine.

So the answer to this riddle: The move/copy will pause and resume when you log back in.

Thank you @Tej Kiran and @user2935726, for your answers and tool suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can resume your operation if it was last interrupted by  shutdown / log-out / Power Cut or any reason. Bucket Explorer allows you to resume your pending process using pending process queue option. You can view here all pending queue list and select your desire queue to process.
http://goo.gl/LWUQuq

[Disclosure : I am one of the developer of BucketExplorer]